# Prove a quotient space and a subspace are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that $V=V_1+V_2$. Let $\alpha$ be a basic for $V_1 \cap V_2$. Extend $\alpha$ to a basic $\alpha \cup \alpha_1$ for $V_1$ and $\alpha \cup \alpha_2$ for $V_2$. (where $\alpha$, $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are pairwise disjoint). Define $V'=span\,\alpha_2$.

I need to prove that $V/V_1$ is isomorphic to $V'$. I tried to prove that $V=V_1 \oplus V'$ but failed. Also I tried to construct an isomorphism but found out that it isn't well-defined. Any thoughts about this question?

Comment: Yes. But the most difficult part is how to construct such a mapping. Do you have any idea? @MatthewH.

Comment: Try and show that $\alpha \cup \alpha_1 \cup \alpha_2$ forms a basis for $V$. Once you do this you'll be able to show that $V$ is a direct sum of $V_1$ and $V'$

Comment: It was my first approach. But I couldn't prove the linear independence of this basic. @MatthewH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms: if you can find a linear map $f:V\to V$ whose image is $V'$ and whose kernel is $V_1$, then $V/V_1\cong V'$.

Assuming that $\alpha_1\cup\alpha\cup\alpha_2$ is a basis of $V$, such a map is easy to construct: make $f$ send every element of $\alpha_2$ to itself and every element of $\alpha_1\cup\alpha$ to $0$, and then extend linearly. The image is clearly the span of $\alpha_2$, which is $V'$, and the kernel is clearly the span of $\alpha_1\cup\alpha$, which is $V_1$.

The only possible issue is that this map may not be well defined if $\alpha_1\cup\alpha\cup\alpha_2$ isn't a basis. So we have to prove that it is.
It's clearly a generating set, since it contains bases of $V_1$ and $V_2$, which in turn generate $V$ due to $V=V_1+V_2$. So only linear independence remains to be shown.

For this, consider a linear combination of elements of $\alpha_1\cup\alpha\cup\alpha_2$. It can be written as $v_1+v+v_2$, where each of the vectors is in the span of the basis with the corresponding indices. We have to show that this linear combination can only be $0$ if the vectors themselves are $0$ (some care needs to be taken here: why does the actual, full linear combination have to be trivial if these three vectors are 0?). Now assume $v_1+v+v_2=0$ but $v_2\neq0$. Then $v_2=-v_1-v$. But then $v_2\in V_1$. But $v_2$ is a linear combination of elements of $\alpha_2$, whose span contains only elements of $V_2$ which are not already contained in $V_1\cap V_2$ (other than $0$). In other words, $\alpha_2$ does not span any nonzero elements of $V_1$, meaning that $v_2$ must be zero. Apply the same argument to $v_1$, and then you have that $0+v+0=0$, meaning that $v$, too, must be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to the collection of "basis" vectors as a "basis" and the individual vectors in them as "basis elements" or "basis vectors".

Just follow what the question tells you. I am not assuming finite dimension.

Now you have $\alpha,\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}$ are pairwise disjoint sets.

Let $\alpha_{1}'=\alpha\cup\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}'=\alpha\cup\alpha_{2}$

Now any vector in $V$ can be written as $w_{1}+w_{2}$ where $v_{i}\in V_{i}$.

But $\displaystyle w_{1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}c_{i}v_{i}$ for $v_{i}\in\alpha_{1}'$.

Of these say $\{v_{1},v_{2},...v_{k_1}\}\in \alpha$ and $\{v_{k_1+1},..v_{n_{1}}\}\in\alpha_{1}$

And $\displaystyle w_{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{k_2}d_{i}x_{i}+\sum_{i=k_2+1}^{n_2}d_{i}x_{i}$ such that $\{x_{1},x_{2},...x_{k_{2}}\}\in \alpha$ and $\{x_{k_{2}+1},...x_{n_2}\}\in\alpha_{2}$.

Then $$w_{1}+w_{2}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k_1}c_{i}v_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{k_2}d_{i}x_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}c_{i}v_{i}\right)+\left(\sum_{i=k_2+1}^{n_2}d_{i}x_{i}\right)$$.

So the $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k_1}c_{i}v_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{k_2}d_{i}x_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}c_{i}v_{i}\right)$ is from $V_{1}$ and $\left(\sum_{i=k_2+1}^{n_2}d_{i}x_{i}\right)$ is from $V'$.

Now if $v\in V\cap V'$ . Then $v\in Span(\alpha_{2})$ and $v\in Span(\alpha\cup\alpha_{1})$ .

But as $\alpha_{2},\alpha$ and $\alpha_{1}$ are pairwise disjoint. So $\alpha_{2}\cap\left(\alpha\cup\alpha_{1}\right)=\phi$ and $\alpha_{2}\cup\left(\alpha\cup\alpha_{1}\right)$ is a basis for $V$. Thus the spans are also disjoint.

Hence you have $V=V\oplus V'$.

Now define $f:V\to V'$ by $f(v_{1}+v')=v'$ such that $v_{1}\in V_{1}$ and $v'\in V'$ This map is well defined as $V=V\oplus V'$ and it is surjective. Now it is easy to see that the kernel is $V_{1}$. And hence by Isomorphism Theorem you have $V/V_{1}\cong V'$.

If you assume finite dimension then it is much easier and you can work with the explicit basis elements. But this is more general.

Comment: Why can't you work with the basis elements in infinite dimensions?

Comment: You can. It is just that the number of basis elements are not fixed. So you have to take care of indices at each steps. It is nothing too complicated but it becomes a little tedius trying to keep up with the notations and indices used